# return string from given list with spaces between words - sml

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have to write a SML function that returns a sentence consisting of words separated by spaces in the given list. I have to use at least one of foldl/foldr/map functions.

This is what I wrote:

```
fun add_spaces nil = ""
  | add_spaces(x::xs) = foldr (fn (x,xs) => (add_spaces x)^" "^xs) x [xs];

add_spaces(["Testing","function","with","this","sentence"]);
```

But that function brings a reversed string (sentence this with function Testing). I read in the internet that can be solved by reversing list ([xs] in this case right?) but how can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `add_spaces` uses `foldr` in a beautifully convoluted but likely misunderstood way.

A regular recursive function, which won't satisfy the criterion of using foldl/foldr/map, is,

```
fun add_spaces [] = ""
  | add_spaces [s] = s
  | add_spaces (s::ss) = s ^ " " ^ add_spaces ss
```

A similar function relying on folding for its recursion would follow a pattern,

```
fun add_spaces [] = ""
  | add_spaces (s1::ss) = fold<l/r> (fn (s,res) => ...) s1 ss
```

where `...` explicitly does *not* refer to `add_spaces`. Thus, you have at least two instruments to guide the order in which your items arrive. One being the order in which you refer to `s` and `res` inside the anonymous function in the above template, and the other being your choice of `foldl` and `foldr`.

Notice also that `foldl` and `foldr` will traverse the list from different directions; from the left and from the right, respectively. To illustrate the order, try and fold with something that results in side-effects and see which effects arrive first:

```
- ​foldl (fn (s, _) => print (s^"\n")) () ["Hello", "World!"];
Hello
World!
> val it = () : unit
- ​foldr (fn (s, _) => print (s^"\n")) () ["Hello", "World!"];
World!
Hello
```